# How to start a new Activity with an if-statement without onCreate method?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclick

I basically want to start new Activities in each condition, but here is the problem: I want the new Activity to start when an "if-statement" is true. So when the user reaches a certain position in counter, let's say 2, the intended activity should start. Thanks in advance!

Here is some code:

```
public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<Model>models;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Model> models, Context context) {
        this.models = models;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title, desc;

        imageView=view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        title=view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc=view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        imageView.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage());
        title.setText(models.get(position).getTitle());
        desc.setText(models.get(position).getDesc());


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//HERE IS MY PROBLEM
                if(position == 0){
                    //start activity1
                } else if(position == 1){
                    //start activity2
                }else if(position == 2){
                    //start activity3
                }else if(position == 3){
                    //start activity4
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Click the exit button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        container.addView(view,0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adapters are not allowed to start activities. Instead, let the adapter tell the activity in which it is hosted that "position X" was clicked and then the activity can decide what to do based on that, such as starting the next activity

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: @TimCastelijns There is nothing stopping an Adapter from starting an Activity.  In fact its quite common.  You may have a style rule where you try to avoid it for some reason, but it is absolutely not a rule of Android.

Comment: @GabeSechan Of course. By saying "not allowed" I was referring to adapters not having a startActivity method, I could have worded it better. While possible as you pointed out, I indeed wouldn't encourage anyone to pass a context to the adapter to use that to call startActivity, hence my other suggestion

Comment: @GabeSechan ,  I am a beginner and I didn't understand some of your answers. I wish if you could help with some code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked well:

view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(position == 0){
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),Levels.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
```